# Cannot open transaction cause it is null (Junit)

Tags: java, junit, spring-test

I have this unit test that started showing an error after I entered these two new parameters connection and notification.
I tried to make the mock but it is showing the error "Cannot open transaction cause it is null", can someone help me?

```
    protected int getTotalRecords(Connection connection, Statement statement, final String sql, NotificationData notification) {
    int rows = 0;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try(ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(buildCountRecordsSQL(sql))) {
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            rows = resultSet.getInt("ROWS_COUNT");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        try{
            SEEntityManager.rollbackAndReOpenTransaction();
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            rs = statement.executeQuery(notification.getFieldSql());
            return rows = BROKE_SQL;
        }catch (final SQLException e1){
            logger.error(e1.getMessage(), e1);
        }
    }
    logger.debug("Total records: "+rows);
    return rows;
}
```

Test Junit

```
@Test
public void verifyExceptionCountRecords() throws SQLException{
    Mockito.when(resultSet.next()).thenThrow(new SQLException());
    assertTrue(daoDefault.getTotalRecords(Mockito.mock(Connection.class), statement, "", notification)==0);
    Mockito.verify(resultSet, Mockito.never()).getInt("ROWS_COUNT");    
}
```

Tests in error:

```
Cannot open transaction cause it is null
```